# is that possible to failover to a secondary host by using rxnetty after first host failed

Tags: error-handling, rx-java, reactive-programming, failover, rx-netty

I am newbie in rxnetty. I am trying to handle the error by retryWhen, but I am stuck with the original observable which is connected/will connect to the my first host. Is there a way to failover to secondary host?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 0.5.x, then you can use the load balancer abstraction to achieve this. The below example demonstrates a way to do it(it uses repeat() but you can replace it with retryWhen())

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty/tree/0.5.x/rxnetty-examples/src/main/java/io/reactivex/netty/examples/http/loadbalancing

If you are using 0.4.x you have to build this yourself on top of RxNetty.

Comment: Thank for reply. Let's say I create an observable o1 that will connect to VIP v1 and I subscribe an observer ob1 to it, after subscribed, the connection attempt is failed, I want retry once, but to connect to different VIP v2 and still observed by the same observer ob1. Here is what I tried just now. (a) In Func1 passed into retryWhen, I create new observable o2 to connect to VIP v2 and subscribe ob1 to o2. (b) in the mean while I return an empty observable (flatmap Observable<? extends Throwable>)  so that there will be no retry for o1. But I still get onError, how ro resovle that? thanks

Comment: Following above. Here is the result (1) on wire, everything is correct, 2 writes and 1 received. (2) The observer gets onNext and OnCompleted notification, which is GOOD (3) my observer still get onError call with the exception, which is BAD.  How can I stop o1 to emit the exception? Thanks

Comment: I tried alternative way to put retry different VIP in lift, which works better (1) handle the IO exception in onError before passing into child observer (2) The observer is handy that is passed in by the parameter so that can be chained to another observable. Do not know what the side-effect is, any advise? Thanks.

Comment: If you share the code here, it will be easier for me to understand and suggest.